# The argument type 'Stream<dynamic>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot>?'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use StreamBuilder to show a stream of text messages from an firestore database. But for some reason the argument type of Stream can't be assigned to the parameter of `Querysnapshot`. If I get rid of the `Querysnapshot` the stream builder doesn't show the error anymore but then I get an error:

> The getter 'documents' isn't defined for the type 'Object'

Can anyone help me out with this problem?

```
Widget ChatMessageList() {
return StreamBuilder(
  stream: chatMessagesStream,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.documents.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return MessageTile(snapshot.data!.documents[index].data['message']);
      },
    );
  },
);
```

}

Comment: Change the `StreamBuilder(...)` to `StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(...)`

Answer (score 1):

This kind of message appears because dart does not know what kind of object `snapshot.data` is.
You probably need to specify the expected type that will be returned from your stream. What does chatMessagesStream return? If it is `Stream<Bar>`, then write `(context, AsyncSnapshot<Bar> snapshot)`, like in the official example [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html)

Also, you should not do calls directly to firebase from your widgets. That is going to create lots of copy-paste and messy code.
You can find an example of a cleaner architecture here :
[real-time-updates-with-streambuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68656842/real-time-updates-with-streambuilder-in-flutter-and-google-maps-firestore/68765612?noredirect=1#comment121530202_68765612)

It will be a little extra work to set it up, but it will definitely pay off quickly ass you include more calls in your code.

Comment: Yes thank you this worked I made the return type of chatMessageStream QuerySnapshot.